# Is there an API for the Google Plus Events

Tags: google-plus

Google Plus recently added events, but have they added API methods to access the public data?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The REST API has limited support for reading public activities at this time.

You can use the activities APIs to see the activities created for public events, and determine that they are events by inspecting the URL, but the API does not currently provide access to all of the event metadata.

Here's an example of what you can see for a [public event](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.activities.get?activityId=z13pdphaylvksztxx04cibvggseginlbrp40k&alt=json&_h=7&).

Comment: but the event link is different from the activity id how do you convert link to id ?

Comment: Tell Google to hire more software engineers to work on Google+. ASAP!