# Create Google Plus Events via API

Tags: google-plus

Is there a possibility to create events for Google Plus Communities via an API?

The only related post I could find is this one: [Is there an API for the Google Plus Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382956/is-there-an-api-for-the-google-plus-events) but it only considers requesting events.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, the G+ API is currently [read-only](https://developers.google.com/+/api/).

> ***Note***: The Google+ API currently provides read-only access to public data. All API calls require either an OAuth 2.0 token or an API key.

Cheers

Comment: Any date when this will change?

Comment: Your guess is as good as mine. Consider reading through the docs.

Comment: Did I answer your question? If so, please consider accepting it.

Comment: Good answer, but that sucks Google.