# Publishing Google Hangout as Public

Tags: google-hangouts

I've been trying to get a Google Hangout Published as public today but must be missing something...   I spent a few hours reading posts and rereading the pages on Google + Hangout API also.

1. I went to the Chrome Web Store and paid the $5.
2. I build the API, and also got the oauth2 ID as well. The XML code is in place online like it's supposed to be. I filled out The URLs of your Terms Of Service, Privacy Policy and Support contact information. and checked the box to make it public.

If somebody can help me figure out what's getting me stuck I would greatly appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try launching the hangout app? Try testing with the [test link](https://developers.google.com/+/hangouts/button#test).

Answer (score 0):

Currently (10/2014), Google+ only provides READ ONLY access via their API. I have read that select Google partners have more access to the API but the standard level of access does not allow for write access.

Hope this helps.

Below are references to support my claim above.

Google+ Platform
https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=41#c181

Will Google+ Ever Get A Full Read/Write API?
http://techcrunch.com/2012/12/30/will-google-ever-get-a-full-readwrite-api/

Create Google Plus Events via API
[Create Google Plus Events via API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13772944/create-google-plus-events-via-api)

How to post in google plus wall
[How to post in Google+ wall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7570327/how-to-post-in-google-plus-wall)