# get all events from a Google Plus Community using API

Tags: google-plus

So we are having a great time using a couple of Google+ communities to co-ordinate pair programming events with programmers and students from all around the world:

https://plus.google.com/communities/100279740984094902927
https://plus.google.com/communities/101007836695292894562

However I'd really like to start analyzing the pair programming events, and so want to grab information about the events via the read-only Google API.  I see that there is a mechanism for doing this:

[Is there an API for the Google Plus Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11382956/is-there-an-api-for-the-google-plus-events)

However I am at a loss for how to work out what the activity id is from the event id, or how to request all the events associated with a community.  For example we have this event:

https://plus.google.com/events/cutfjr3ftm3mglt32p54h6fgec0

and if I knew the activity id for it I could use something like this:

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.activities.get?activityId=z13pdphaylvksztxx04cibvggseginlbrp40k&_h=1&

to grab info about the event.  However the event id in the URL is different from the activity id, or at least nothing is returned.  Perhaps because it is a private event?  That said I can't grab info on public "on air" events either.

What I've managed so far is to be able to search for public events in my own activity stream.  From there I can get to an activity id for a public hangout I stared:

z13adpyrwlaytjicm22bvjhjkly0yfctz

which gives me some useful information on that event, but what I'm really after is to get the info on all the events associated with our communities so that we can analyze them and better support them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, there is no support for retrieving posts from a Google+ community with an API. For a period of time, some people were using the [activities methods in the v1 API](http://developers.google.com/+/api/latest/activities) to retrieve posts but this was never supported and eventually stopped working.

This [issue is already posted in the Google+ platform issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=639&q=community&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Component%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) if you want to follow it.

Comment: Thanks for the link to this. It's such a drag that this isn't available for communities.

Comment: Brett, do you know if there has there been any progress on this?

Comment: Don't waste your time visiting the bug tracker. 320 stars and 3 years worth of comments, this will probably never happen