# Posts from Google+ community on the website

Tags: google-api, google-plus

Im trying to figure out whether it's possible to show the posts of my google+ community on a website.

I read the Google+ Web API and HTTP API, but nothing seems to satisfy my request.

I know this is an absolute newbie question. But I appreciate any hint:

is it in general possible?
which API I have to use?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [get all events from a Google Plus Community using API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374135/get-all-events-from-a-google-plus-community-using-api)

Answer (score 1):

The APIs do not provide support for getting any type of Google+ Community post even if they are public. In the past this worked, but it was never supported and has since stopped working.

Comment: Thank you Brett for your input , maybe for the future such an option comes up

Comment: You can "star" the issue at https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=639 to follow along with any news related to this feature request.