# How to get data of community via Google Plus API?

Tags: api, google-plus

For people its ok, but how do it for communities?
For example, how to get all public data of https://plus.google.com/u/0/communities/104034580731500416577 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get all events from a Google Plus Community using API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374135/get-all-events-from-a-google-plus-community-using-api)

Answer (score 5):

Not currently possible. There's an open feature request for it:

https://code.google.com/p/google-plus-platform/issues/detail?id=639