# Is there a Google plus Communities API for Android?

Tags: android, google-plus

I have been searching for quite a while now and can not seem to find any API for `Google+ Communities`, if an API exists would somebody be so kind to provide the link for the reference to the API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't find it on the [official site](https://developers.google.com/+/api/#api) there probably is no such thing in existence. Maybe this post helps you https://stackoverflow.com/a/19374410/2932698

Comment: Thanks that was useful, hopefully one day.

Comment: No problem. One day maybe ;)